# multilevel inheritance with same method names c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, inheritance

I have been stuck in a situation here,It is an existing code which was handed over to me,

```
class A
{
    public string helloworld()
    {
        return "A";
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public string helloworld()
    {

        return "B";
    }
}

class C: B
{
    public string hi()
    {
    if(condition1)
     {
        return helloworld(); // From class A
     }
    else
     {
        return helloworld(); // From class B
     }
    }
}
```

The scenario is such that on a certain condition it should return the method from class A else it should return method from class B
How do I go about achieving this as the output is always 'B'

Comment: This code doesn't compile, condition1 is missing. Please show an example that compiles and demonstrates the behavior you describe. You may also want to look into the virtual and override modifiers.

Comment: You need to call base.helloworld(), for calling method in class A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
class A
{
    public string helloworld()
    {
        return "A";
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public new string helloworld()
    {
        return "B";
    }
}

class C: B
{
   public string hi(bool condition)
   {
      if(condition)
      {
         A instance = this;
         return instance.helloworld(); // From class A
      }
      else
      {
          B instance = this;
          return instance.helloworld(); // From class B
      }
    }
}
```

If you implement a method that hides a method in the base class the compiler warns you about it. To tell your compiler it was intentionall use the New keyword.

To Invoke the implementation in the base class you have to typecast your instance to the type of the baseclass.

Comment: Can you please explain the above answer

Answer (score 6):

```
if (condition1)
{
    return ((A)this).helloworld(); // From class A
}
else
{
    return ((B)this).helloworld(); // From class B
}
```

Also, if source for `B` is under your control, you should add `new` keyword to its implementation of `helloworld` (or better yet, rename it altogether to avoid hiding), but solution in `C.hi` will still be the same.

Comment: Can you please explain the above answer

Comment: polymorphism works on dynamic type: `C` dynamic type is neither `A` nor `B`, but by casting an instance of `C` (i.e., `this`) to either `A` or `B` we can force the dynamic type that we wish, as indicated by the comments in the original code. Without the the cast, the compiler simply falls back on the first parent up the inheritance tree, `B`.